# populate select option from another listbox using c# in razor page

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core

Hy,
I'm trying to fill a listboxB with selected item from another listboxA after a button click.
My HTML code

```
<div class="row" runat="server">
    <div class="m-auto">
        <form method="post">
            <label>Coalition</label>
            <select id="CoalitionList" class="form-control" name="CoalitionList" asp-for="CoalitionList">
                <option value="0" selected disabled>-- Select Coalition --</option>
                <option value="1">Coalition A</option>
                <option value="2">Coalition B</option>
            </select>
            <label>Alliances</label>
            <select id="AllianceList" class="form-control" name="AllianceList" asp-for="AllianceList" asp-items="@Model.AllianceItems" multiple="multiple" size="10">
                <option value="0" selected disabled>-- Select Alliance --</option>
            </select>
            <button name="AddButton" id="AddButton" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" onclick="AddButton_Click">Add</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="form-group">
        <form method="post">
            <label>Coalition A</label>
             //The selected items should display here
            <select id="CoalitionAList" name="CoalitionAList" class="form-control" size="10" asp-items="@Model.SelectedAllianceItems">
            </select>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

my Code behind. How do I access SelectedValue for value field and Displaymemberpath for text field?

```
 public class GenerateChartsModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly DContext _db;
        public GenerateChartsModel(DContext db)
        {
            _db = db;
        }
        [BindProperty]
        public int CoalitionList { get; set; }
        //To Display selected value in CoalitionAList
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> SelectedAllianceItems { get; set; }
        //Storing and passing selected values
        public int AllianceList { get; set; }
        //Displaying items
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> AllianceItems { get; set; } 
        public void OnGet()
        {
            AllianceItems = _db.Alliances.Select(a => new SelectListItem {Value = a.Alliance_Id.ToString(), Text = a.Alliance}).ToList();
        }
        protected void AddButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var SelectedCoalitionList = this.CoalitionList;
            var SelectedAllianceList = this.AllianceList;
            if(SelectedAllianceList != 0 || SelectedCoalitionList != 0)
            {
                SelectedAllianceItems = new List<SelectListItem>()
                {
                    //This doesn't work.
                    new SelectListItem{Value = SelectedAllianceList.ToString(), Text = SelectedAllianceList.ToString()}
                };
            }
        }
    }
```

ON a completely different yet similar topic. my page is not rendered if I try using asp:listbox or anything I've tried with. even though I copied the whole code from docs.microsoft.Is there any reason for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set a debugger in the AddButton_Click event, you can see that this method aren't executed. Generally, in Asp.net core the handler method is prefixed with "On", such as: OnGet(), OnPost(), OnPut() etc. When you click the button, it will submit the form to this handler method, instead of using the Button Click event (Like this the asp.net server side click event). More detail information about handler methods in asp.net core, you could check this link: [Handler Methods in Razor Pages](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/handler-methods).

So, you could modify the code as below:

Code in the Index.cshtml

```
<div class="row" runat="server">
    <div class="m-auto">
        <form method="post">
            <label>Coalition</label>
            <select id="CoalitionList" class="form-control" asp-for="CoalitionList" asp-items="@Model.CoalitionItems">
                <option value="0" selected disabled>-- Select Coalition --</option> 
            </select>
            <label>Alliances</label>
            <select id="AllianceList" class="form-control" asp-for="AllianceList" asp-items="@Model.AllianceItems" multiple="multiple" size="10">
                <option value="0" selected disabled>-- Select Alliance --</option>
            </select>
            <button name="AddButton" id="AddButton" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" onclick="AddButton_Click">Add</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="form-group">
        <form method="post">
            <label>Coalition A</label>
            //The selected items should display here
            <select id="CoalitionAList" name="CoalitionAList" class="form-control" size="10" asp-items="@Model.SelectedAllianceItems">
            </select>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Code in the Index.cshtml.cs
Note: since you are using a listbox, I suppose you may want to select multiple items, so, I change the AllianceList data type from `int` to `List<int>`. If you don't like that, change it back to `int`.

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly ILogger<IndexModel> _logger;

    public IndexModel(ILogger<IndexModel> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }
    [BindProperty]
    public int CoalitionList { get; set; }
    //To Display selected value in CoalitionAList
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> SelectedAllianceItems { get; set; }

    //Storing and passing selected values 
    [BindProperty]
    public List<int> AllianceList { get; set; }
    //Displaying items
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> AllianceItems { get; set; } 
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CoalitionItems { get; set; }

    public IActionResult OnGet()
    {
        AllianceItems = GetAllianceItems();
        CoalitionItems = GetCoalitionItems();

        return Page();
    } 

    public List<SelectListItem> GetAllianceItems()
    {
        //test data
        return new List<SelectListItem>()
        {
            new SelectListItem(){ Value = "1001", Text ="AAA"},
             new SelectListItem(){ Value = "1002", Text ="BBB"},
              new SelectListItem(){ Value = "1003", Text ="CCC"},
               new SelectListItem(){ Value = "1004", Text ="DDD"},
                new SelectListItem(){ Value = "1005", Text ="EEE"},
        };
    }
    public List<SelectListItem> GetCoalitionItems()
    {
        return new List<SelectListItem>()
        {
            new SelectListItem(){ Value = "1", Text ="Coalition A"},
             new SelectListItem(){ Value = "2", Text ="Coalition B"}, 
        };
    }
    public IActionResult OnPost()
    {
        var SelectedCoalitionList = this.CoalitionList;
        var SelectedAllianceList = this.AllianceList;
        if (SelectedAllianceList.Count> 0 || SelectedCoalitionList != 0)
        {
            SelectedAllianceItems = new List<SelectListItem>()
            { 
                new SelectListItem{Value = String.Join(",", SelectedAllianceList), Text = String.Join(",", SelectedAllianceList)}
            };
        }

        //re-populate the ListBox A and the DropDownlist
        AllianceItems = GetAllianceItems();
        CoalitionItems = GetCoalitionItems();

        return Page();
    }
}
```

The output:

[image]