# Selectlist onchange should prepopulate textfield values in Razor Pages

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have two selectlist in my razor page.
When i select a value from the first selectlist ,it should prepopulate related data into the textfields.
When i select a value from the second selectlist ,it should prepopulate value in the other txtfields.

How can i achieve this in Razor Pages?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63054303/populate-select-option-from-another-listbox-using-c-sharp-in-razor-page

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get related data from backend,here is a demo:

```
<form method="post">

</form>
<select id="a" name="a">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
    
    </select>
    <input  id="a-related"/>
<script>

            $('#a').on('change', function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '?handler=GetData',
                    headers: {
                        RequestVerificationToken: $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val()
                    },
                    data: { "a": $("#a").val() },
                    dataType: "json"
                }).done(function (data) {
                    $("#a-related").val(data);
                });
            });
</script>
```

backend:

```
public IActionResult OnPostGetData(string a)
        {
            //get data from db with the data passed
            //i return fake data to test
            return new JsonResult("relatedMessage-"+a);

        }
```

result:
[image]

Comment: Hi @Yiyi,how can i do this dynamically,this one i know,i want to fetch the value from database .thanks for the support

Comment: I have updated my answer to add a demo to pass data to  backend,and get data from backend,and add data to input.